# MySQL query is duplicating name field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a SQL query that returns the total number of session check in per attendee.  However, when I ran the below query, it repeats the full name over everything.

Try different tpes of query but still getting the same results

```
SELECT
CONCAT(ea.first_name, ' ', ea.last_name) as full_name,
es.name AS name,
es.event_id AS event_id,
(   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT esc.event_attendee_id)
    FROM event_session_checkin esc
    WHERE(esc.event_session_id =es.id) 
) AS attendee_count
FROM event_session es, event_attendee ea;
```

results:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|full_name |event_name |event_id   |attendee_count|
+-------------------------------------------------+
|anita_roy |name_exam  |event_exam1|      2       |
|anita_roy |name_exam  |event_exam2|      3       |
|anita_roy |name_exam  |event_exam3|      5       |
|anita_roy |name_exam  |event_exam4|      6       |
|anita_roy |name_exam  |event_exam5|      7       |
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`!!!.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `FROM event_session es, event_attendee ea` yields a combinatorially exploding result set, with all possible pairs  of rows from the two tables. Read about `FROM ... JOIN ... ON ... `

Comment: thank you @O.Jones im a web dev guy so this is a little bit complex for me.   I ran sql queries before but either I am complicating this too much or I am not tackling from the right angle.

Answer (score -1):

Try to

```
SELECT CONCAT(ea.first_name, ' ', ea.last_name) as full_name,es.name AS name,
enter code here es.event_id AS event_id,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT esc.event_attendee_id)
        FROM event_session_checkin esc
        WHERE(esc.event_session_id =es.id) ) AS attendee_count
FROM
event_session es, event_attendee ea group by full_name;
```

Comment: i assume you didn't read @O. Jones  's warning comment to the top related to the `FROM event_session es, event_attendee ea`..  Also this query is misusing ISO/ANSI GROUP BY SQL standards this is not how it should be used..

Answer (score -1):

Of course, because you didn't specify how the tables were related!

```
SELECT * FROM person,address
```

This query above will just return every person combined with every address. It ignores any relationship between the tables and if there are 200 people and 100 addresses it will churn out 20,000 results of each person at every address. The person names will each be repeated 100 times, one for eachaddress. The addresses will each be repeated 200 times, one for every person. Even if you declared foreign keys etc between the table - they don't matter; mysql will not use them to infer relationships between tables. The database **has to be told explicitly** what column of person related to what column of address:

```
SELECT * FROM person p INNER JOIN address a on p.home_address_id = a.id
```

Tables can be joined in multiple times:

```
SELECT * FROM  
  person p 
  INNER JOIN address ha on p.home_address_id = ha.id
  INNER JOIN address wa on p.work_address_id = wa.id
```

Please read, absorb, understand and rewrite your query so you explicitly declare which column in `event_session` relates to which column in `event_attendee`